# Print a PDF report using the printer directly without downloading in Odoo

Tags: printing, odoo

I'm a beginner with Odoo so my question might seem stupid, but i really tried to do it alone and i couldn't

so the question is : i want to reproduce the re-print of POS module in asset module. well I have a pdf report and i want to print it directly without downloading it. using the print function of the browser, i tried to understand how the POS module is working, it uses proxy, and i couldn't find how it prints the  receipts

what i want to know is how to tell the browser to print the pdf doc ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a module for that by OCA here is the github repo

https://github.com/OCA/report-print-send/tree/8.0/base_report_to_printer

it's available for openerp, odoo8 and odoo9

Comment: this solution print the pdf file directly, how to display it in the browser first ?